AJAX error when trying to edit Better Exposed Filter settings on a table view
In my D10 site, I'm attempting to put an exposed form on my table View via the Better Exposed Filters module. I can enable BEF, but when I click its settings link, I get an error message on the page:

Oops, something went wrong. Check your browser's developer console for more details.

And this in the console:
Uncaught 
Object { message: "\nAn AJAX HTTP error occurred.\nHTTP Result Code: 200\nDebugging information follows.\nPath: /admin/structure/views/ajax/display/site_content/page_1/exposed_form_options\nStatusText: parsererror\nResponseText: Fatal error: Declaration of Drupal\\select2\\Plugin\\better_exposed_filters\\filter\\Select2::defaultConfiguration() must be compatible with Drupal\\better_exposed_filters\\Plugin\\better_exposed_filters\\filter\\FilterWidgetBase::defaultConfiguration(): array in /code/web/modules/contrib/select2/src/Plugin/better_exposed_filters/filter/Select2.php on line 21"

The error is referencing Select2 which is installed an enabled. Both BEF and Select2 are up to date.
Any idea what is going on here?

I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report.

Yes. This is a bug in Select2, or one of its two closely-related bugs.
